# Copy-pasting data a number of times based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets: `DataEntry` and `Datasheet`. There is data written on `DataEntry` on `C4` and `Number (Quantity of Data)` on `E4`. I want data to be pasted on `Datasheet` based on number of times mentioned on `DataEntry E4`.

For Eg. Data Mentioned on `DataEntry` is

```
C4 = Markers
E4 = 5
```

So I want entry of this Markers 5 times pasted in `Datasheet` on respective rows with Date in next column and so on other items to be added below last data:

How it would look like in `DataSheet`:

```
  A2       B2
Markers 01-Jan-14
Markers 01-Jan-14
Markers 01-Jan-14
Markers 01-Jan-14
Markers 01-Jan-14
```

Can somebody help me with VBA codes for above

Comment: `01-Jan014` -- should this be `01-Jan-14`? Also, have you tried recording a macro and seeing how it works?

Comment: Tried recording Macro but Macro is not able to show loop for pasting Items based on defined quantity. i.e. Pasting Values N number of times based on given number in C4.

Comment: If there is data already in `Datasheet`, do you want it to be replaced or just to append the new data to the next empty row?

Comment: Yes, I want to append new data to next empty row

Comment: Done. See my answer below if it suffices. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub CopyBasedOnQuantity()

    Dim DataEntry As Worksheet, DataSht As Worksheet
    Dim ItemName As Range, ItemCount As Range
    Dim NRow As Long, TargetCell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set DataEntry = .Sheets("DataEntry")
        Set DataSht = .Sheets("Datasheet")
    End With

    With DataEntry
        Set ItemName = .Range("C4")
        Set ItemCount = .Range("E4")
    End With

    With DataSht
        NRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Set TargetCell = .Range("A" & NRow)
        TargetCell.Resize(ItemCount.Value, 1).Value = ItemName.Value
        TargetCell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(ItemCount.Value, 1).Value = Date
    End With

End Sub
```

**Screenshots:**

***Set-up:***

[image]

***Result:***

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: @BK201 i got my WS event firing and decided to work on this using it :D haha

Comment: @L42: I originally planned on doing that until I realized that it's as messy as hell to maintain that. Everytime I edit the number first, nightmare ensues. :D

Comment: @BK201 haha see my edit, it should fix your nightmares. :D LOL

Answer (score 1):

This is my version using `Worksheet Event`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim entry As Range, count As Range, dest As Range
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim query As Integer

On Error Goto errhandler
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set entry = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataEntry").Range("C4")
Set count = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataEntry").Range("E4")

Set dest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataSheet").Range("A" & _
    Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

If Not Intersect(Target, count) Is Nothing Then
    query = MsgBox("Copy Data?", vbYesNo)
    If query = 7 Then Exit Sub
    i = Target.Value
    For j = 1 To i
        Target.Offset(0, -2).Copy dest
        With dest.Offset(0, 1)
            .Value = Date
            .NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yy"
        End With
        Set dest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A" & _
            Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next
End If

continue:
Application.EnableEvents = True

Exit Sub
errhandler:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume continue

End Sub
```

Hope this helps.
Everytime you change value in `E4` data win `C4` will be copied to your `DataSheet`.
Code in `Sheet`, not in `Module`.

Comment: +1: Nice event-based version, and nice handle with the `MsgBox`. :)